# Left or right invertible implies Invertibility of compact operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Suppose $K \in \mathcal{B}(X)$ is a compact linear operator, where $X$ is a Banach space. Suppose $I-K$ is either left or right invertible. Show that $I-K$ is invertible and $I-(I-K)^{-1}$ is a compact linear operator.

I am not sure how to proceed with this problem. Intuitively it seems to me this holds because the compact operators form a two-sided ideal in the space of bounded linear operators. Can someone please help me.

Comment: With the Fredholm alternative, you can conclude that if $I - K$ is left-invertible, then it must be invertible. By considering the adjoint of $K$, you can conclude that if $I - K$ is right-invertible (so that $(I - K)^*$ is left-invertible), $I - K$ must be invertible.

Comment: For the latter part of the problem, consider the product
$$
(I - K)[I - (I - K)^{-1}].
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann why not post this as an answer?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you very much, this has been really helpful.